# Inserting multiple data into the database with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, multithreading

I think this is my first question here and hope to be as clear as possible. I have the fallowing code.

```
def index_service_name
@currentService = Feed.where("name = '#{params[:name]}'").first

serviceId = @currentService['id']
serviceName = @currentService['name']
serviceFeedUrl = @currentService['feedUrl']

feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(serviceFeedUrl)

  feed.entries.reverse.each do |entry|
    case serviceName
      when 'service1', 'service2'
        uniqueId = entry.url.match(/\d+$/)[0]
        postContent = Nokogiri::HTML( entry.content ).css('img').map{ |i| i['src'] }.first # this would be an array.
      else
        uniqueId = entry.url
        postContent = entry.content
    end

    isIndexed = Post.where("post_unique_id = '#{uniqueId}' AND post_service = '#{serviceId}'")

    if postContent =~ %r{\Ahttps?://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)\z}i
      isImage = true
    elsif postContent =~ %r{http?s://(.*)/maxW500/}i
      isImage = true
    end

    if isIndexed.empty? && isImage
      sleep 1.seconds
      Post.create(post_service: serviceId, post_service_name: serviceName, title: entry.title, content: postContent, url: entry.url, post_unique_id: uniqueId)
    end
  end
```

I trigger the services using a regular URL (/something/service/service1, /something/service/service2). If I trigger them in the same time, it seems that that every one of them is waiting for the other one to end (thus in my DB the data is stored first from service1 and afterwards from service2). I'm thinking this has to do something with multithreading which as I understand that ROR doesn't have support for it yet.

I'm a newbie on ROR so please be gentle. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the app?  Unicorn, script/rails server, or something else?

Comment: basic rails server (rails s in console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MRI ruby, then you dont have parallel multithreading. MRI has green threads which dont run in parallel. If you use JRuby implementation of ruby, you will be able to use parallel multithreads.

Either way, start 2 instances of your server and you will be able to run that code in parallel. use `rails s -p 3000` and `rails s -p 3001` to start 2 servers: port 3001 and 3000. Then try accessing one url on port 3000 and another on port 3001. that way your code will run in parallel.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So basically, if I have 10 services I need to start up 10 instances of my application? That doesn't sound very good. Is there an alternative? Changing something? Thanks.

Comment: That's for development. In production you will have apache + passenger which will auto-start processes and run on the same port and route requests to available process

Comment: Ok. I will try to switch my tag to production and see whats happening. I'm currently working on localhost on a macbook. Do I need to start Apache as well?

Comment: just switching tag to production will not help. you actually need to install apache and passenger fusion. then you need to edit your apache conf file to point to public directory of your project and enable passenger so apache starts serving up rails. please research how to set up apache and passenger if you want to do that.

Comment: Hmm, ok. To much work for "just testing" an app. No multithread either... I'm not seeing ROR a language to use in the near future (at least for my apps). Thanks for all your help, but I will probably move to Laravel (on PHP).